# How to wake up device using Alarm clock?

Tags: java, android

I use the following code for setting repeating events in `AlarmManager`:

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 
    PERIOD, getPendingIntent(time));
```

Code for receiver:

```
public class NotificationsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_INFO="notification_info";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       playSound(context);
       Intent i=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);
    }

    private void playSound(Context context) {
        Uri notification=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification).play();
    }
}
```

There is some problem - I need to play music when the event happens, but if my device is in sleeping I don't hear any signal! But when I wake up device I hear music. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i have to do this, I create the following class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public abstract class WakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can call `WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());` to wake up your phone, but don't forget to call `WakeLocker.release();` when your action is finished.

Also, add the following permission to your manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Hope this help.